# GObject.idle_add(func), my program hangs

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk, gobject

I don't know why my program hangs, I've already read several topics about this.

The result is that when i **click on Config_Window_Button1**, then my **Config_Window freezes** for a while, **the time requested by `time.sleep()`**.

Then Network_Window appears but **`GObject.idle_add()` seems to being run just one time** (the fraction is adjusted to 0.25); i can't see any movement in that progressbar, and the point of interest is that **the `print("def pulse running")` is regularly running**.

So:

**1)** *why Config_Window freezes for S seconds, where time.sleep(S) is after GObject.idle_add()?*

**2)** *why my GUI hasn't being updated?*

```
GObject.threads_init()
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('UI2.glade')
builder.get_object('Config_Window').show()

progressbar = builder.get_object('Progressbar1')
progressbar.set_inverted(True)
fraction = 0.0
builder.get_object('Config_Window_Button1').connect('clicked', collega_GUI) 


def collega_GUI(widget, args=()):

    builder.get_object('boxNetwork').show_all()
    builder.get_object('Network_Window').show()
    progressbar.set_pulse_step(0.25)

    pulse()
    print 'collega_GUI has ended'


def pulse():

    while True:
        GObject.idle_add(progressbar.pulse)
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'def pulse running'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `while True` loop inside the `pulse` function. This means that control never leaves `pulse` and returns to your event loop, which means the GTK can never actually update the UI. You can fix this by repeatedly scheduling `pulse` to run using `timeout_add`, instead of using an infinite loop.

```
def pulse():
    progress_bar.pulse()
    GObject.timeout_add(1000, pulse) # pulse it again in 1 second.
    print 'def pulse running'
```

**Edit:**

It looks like you were actually trying to use multiple threads here, in which case you could keep `pulse` as is, as long as you actually launch it in a background thread:

```
def collega_GUI(widget, args=()):

    builder.get_object('boxNetwork').show_all()
    builder.get_object('Network_Window').show()
    progressbar.set_pulse_step(0.25)

    self.pulse_thread = threading.Thread(target=pulse)
    self.pulse_thread.start()
    print 'collega_GUI has ended'


def pulse():
    while True:
        GObject.idle_add(progressbar.pulse)
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'def pulse running'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. You've already replied me in a very similar question, this time i was going to try this: 
http://manojbits.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/multithreading-in-pygtk/

Comment: i've also noticed that time.sleep() and GObject.idle_add() don't work together as expected (even without a while loop), because the GUI freezes. Do you know some more about this?

Comment: @Jimmy5nomama you're only using one thread here, so any time you use `time.sleep`, you're going to block the event loop for however long you sleep. That's the difference between your code and the example you linked to; the example is using a background thread to run the infinite loop, so the GUI is never blocked.  If you were to run `pulse` in a background thread,  your example would work fine.

Comment: except that you *must* *not* use GTK+ API from different threads: only one thread can modify the GUI, and it's the thread that called Gtk.main().

Comment: @ebassi You can use GTK's API from another thread as long as you only access widgets via `Gobject.idle_add`. Or maybe that's what you're trying to say - don't use GTK+ directly, only use `gobject.idle_add`/`object.timeout_add`?

Comment: @dano you cannot access GTK API from different threads, that's just how it works. if you have a thread running a blocking operation (`sleep`, in the code above) then you can use `GObject.idle_add` to schedule functions to be called from within the same thread context of the main loop.

Comment: anyway the example you've coded with background thread doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Jimmy5nomama can you be more specific about what isn't working?

Comment: @dano the gui hasn't being updated, while i receive reguarly the print

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana Are you actually starting the event loop somewhere in the code? I didn't include that in the example itself.

Comment: @dano so, do you want to say that i should starting a background thread in the main thread where i call Gtk.main() ?

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana No, the main thread should call `Gtk.main()`. The background thread runs the infinite loop and updates the GUI in the main thread via `idle_add`.

Comment: @dani what I really want is a thread.join(), lock.acquire() (lock that has to be released from another thread), **something, placed after self.pulse_thread.start(), that let me block def collega_GUI (raised by an event call) from going ahead**